# custom UIButton with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, drawrect

I'm making my own custom UIButton.
I subcalssed the UIButton class and drawRect function
this is my code:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{

    let midPoint = CGPointMake(rect.midX, rect.midY)

    if !self.selected
    {
        let redCircle = UIBezierPath()
        let redCircleRadius = rect.width - self.whiteCirlceWidth - self.spaceBetweenCirclesWidth

        redCircle.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(rect.midX, rect.midY), radius: redCircleRadius,
            startAngle: 0 , endAngle: 2 * CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = redCircle.CGPath

        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4.0

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)


        let whiteCircle = UIBezierPath()
        whiteCircle.addArcWithCenter(midPoint,
            radius: self.bounds.width / 2,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat(M_PI) , clockwise: true)
        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        whiteCircle.fill()
    }
    else
    {

        let whiteCircle = UIBezierPath()
        whiteCircle.addArcWithCenter(midPoint,
            radius: self.bounds.width / 2,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat(M_PI) , clockwise: true)
        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        whiteCircle.fill()


        let blankCircle = UIBezierPath()
        blankCircle.addArcWithCenter(midPoint, radius: rect.width - self.whiteCirlceWidth - self.spaceBetweenCirclesWidth,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
        UIColor.blackColor().setFill()
        blankCircle.fill()


        var rect = CGRect(origin: midPoint, size: CGSizeMake(rect.width / 2, rect.width / 2))
        rect.origin.x -= rect.origin.x / 2
        rect.origin.y -= rect.origin.y / 2

        let roundedRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 3)
        UIColor.redColor().setFill()
        roundedRect.fill()

    }



}
```

when I click on the button I do this

```
@IBAction func recordBtnClicked(sender : UIButton)
{
    self.recordBtn.selected = !self.recordBtn.selected
    self.recordBtn.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

but it doesn't change anything!.
I checked in the debugger and it does the right block of code .
I checked two blocks and they do the right drawing
what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out it was because I added a subLayer and it stucks and I didn't remove it ' so I changed the code and didn't used the sublayer.
you can remove the subLayer each time you call drawRect